# BackboneJS click event not firing after page template loaded by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, backbone.js, underscore.js

BackboneJS event handler

```
 function alertTest(){ alert('alertTest has fired.');}

 Views.Profile = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.list-profile-wrapper',
    events: {
        'click ' : 'testmtd',
    },
    initialize: function() {
        alert("this is in init");
    },...
```

Context of the problem:
This is on a WordPress site. I have an UnderscoreJS template that is loaded with AJAX when the users click on a pagination number. This UnderscoreJS template has the "list-profile-wrapper" class in it, but does not fire the BackboneJS event handler. The initialize function does not even get fired as the alert message doesn't appear. **This only happens with page templates that are loaded with AJAX.** Pages with similar templates but are not loaded with AJAX do not face this problem.

Comment: Are you running the above code before the UJS template is loaded? Are any errors getting thrown in the console? And do you see the view that's being rendered?

Comment: Yeah. The code runs before the UJS template is loaded. No errors in the console. The UJS template view is rendered, but the Backbone event handler does not fire.

I've tried including a dummy function (alertTest(), edited into the main post above) in the same JS file as the Backbone JS event handler and called it from the UJS template (div onclick()) and it works, but the Backbone event handler still does not work. I think this means the file has successfully loaded, but I still have no idea why the Backbone event handler does not fire.

Comment: My guess is you'll need to load the UJS template before running the code above, so that the view has a DOM element to attach to. Are you seeing warnings/errors in the console?

Comment: The AJAX example can be seen at: https://projectshop.thefussy.co/profiles/ , where the UJS template gets loaded when a user clicks on the pagination numbers or prev/next to load the profiles. (This site does not have the Backbone event handler though, just the AJAX template example.) There're no errors in the console,

Comment: I agree with @GAntoine, the view is instantiated before the UJS template is loaded, so it does not find the .list-profile-wrapper element and the event is not binded.

Comment: Is there some way I can force the event handler to re-run upon loading the UJS template? I've tried assigning the event handler function to a variable and calling it but it didn't work.